# C# WPF / XAML access TextBox from anywhere/any thread help

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, backgroundworker

I'm trying to post to a text box from anywhere in my program, regardless of what thread it's in or what object owns it etc...

I've tried a few things below, all won't work.

**Attempt 1:** tbLog doesn't exist in Cleaning and another thread owns it.

```
namespace MyProgram 
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Cleaning clng = new Cleaning(); 
        }

        public buttonStartTasks_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate { tbLog.Text += "Starting to clean"; }));
                clng.cleanRoom(); 
            }

            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}

namespace Tasks
{
    public class Cleaning
    {
        public void cleanRoom()
        {
            tbLog.Text += "Dusting...."; 
            Thread.Sleep(50000); //work sim
            tbLog.Text += "Sweeping...."; 
            Thread.Sleep(50000); //work sim
            tbLog.Text += "Hanging up clothes...."; 
            Thread.Sleep(50000); //work sim
            tbLog.Text += "Organize shelves...."; 
            Thread.Sleep(50000); //work sim
            tbLog.Text += "Remaining odds and ends...."; 
            Thread.Sleep(50000); //work sim
        }
    }
}
```

**Attempt 2:** I tried to pass tbLog into Cleaning. I got this error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it". Which makes sense.

```
namespace MyProgram 
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Cleaning clng = new Cleaning(tbLog); 
        }

        public buttonStartTasks_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate { tbLog.Text += "!!! Starting to clean !!!"; }));
                clng.cleanRoom(); 
            }

            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}

namespace Tasks
{
    public class Cleaning
    {

        private TextBox LOG { get; set; }

        public Cleaning(TextBox log)
        {
            this.LOG = log; 
        } 

        public void cleanRoom()
        {
            LOG.Text += "Dusting...."; 
            Thread.Sleep(50000); //work sim
            LOG.Text += "Sweeping...."; 
            Thread.Sleep(50000); //work sim
            LOG.Text += "Hanging up clothes...."; 
            Thread.Sleep(50000); //work sim
            LOG.Text += "Organize shelves...."; 
            Thread.Sleep(50000); //work sim
            LOG.Text += "Remaining odds and ends...."; 
            Thread.Sleep(50000); //work sim
        }
    }
}
```

**Attempt 3:** I tried to use Dispatcher in Cleaning and got compile error telling me it doesn't exist. So now I'm stuck. I don't know what else to try. I googled a bunch, but it always comes down to the thread ownership error.

```
if (Dispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate { this.LOG.Text += "No clean for you!"; }));
}
else
{
    this.LOG.Text += "No clean for you!";
}
```

The TextBox for all:

```
<TextBox Name="tbLog"
    Height="200" 
    Width="200"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"  
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
    IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just messing with this yesterday trying to incrementally load a ListBox from another thread.  I got it to work by changing Dispatcher.Invoke() to Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke().

Comment: In case you wonder: Use System.Windows.Application, not System.Windows.Forms.Application

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't just perform actions on controls from other threads than the main UI thread. If you want to do this, you have to use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` from the `Dispatcher`.

A introduction to this can be found [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher), you will also find code examples there which will help you with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best way would be to bind the text property of your textbox to a dependency property, and update the dependency property from your backgroundworker. For the text box's value to update from the thread, you'll need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx).